# Edit texts not working properly android

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Hi I am trying to do a list view with edit text where the user can enter the numbers he wants however my code keeps jumping between editboxes after I add the first character is there a way to stop that? I have tried removing get focus and removing the addTextWatcher. However when I delete the addtextwatcher non of the text is recorded. Please let me know if you need more info since im kind of new to this android life. here is my code for the adapter:
public CreateWKOAdapter(Context context, ArrayList items, ListView listview)
    {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mContext = context;
        this.items = items;
        this.listview = listview;
    }

```
@Override
public int getCount()
{
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public CreateWKOItem getItem(int position)
{
    return items.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position)
{
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    if (convertView == null)
    {
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.create_wko_layout_item, null);
        holder.name_text_view = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_name);
        holder.header = convertView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout1);
        holder.input = convertView.findViewById(R.id.oclick_layout);
        holder.image_view = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.foto_createwko);
        holder.sets_edit_text = (CustomEditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sets_edit_text);
        holder.reps_edit_text = (CustomEditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rep_edit_text);
        holder.checkbox = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_chk);

        holder.header.setTag(holder.input);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    }


    if (visibleindex == position)
    {
        holder.input.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if(holder.sets_edit_text != null)
        {
            final EditText clone = holder.sets_edit_text;
            holder.sets_edit_text.postDelayed(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    clone.requestFocus();
                    Log.i("su", "Request focus");
                }
            }, 300);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        holder.input.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    CreateWKOItem item = getItem(position);

    if(item.isShouldShowCheckBox())
    {
        holder.checkbox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else
    {
        holder.checkbox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    String image_drawable_str = item.getName().toLowerCase().replace(" ", "_");
    Drawable drawable = getImageFromDrawableByString(image_drawable_str);
    if (drawable != null)
    {
        holder.image_view.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    }
    else
    {
        holder.image_view.setImageResource(R.drawable.bg_count);
    }

    holder.sets_edit_text.removeTextWatcher();
    holder.reps_edit_text.removeTextWatcher();

    holder.name_text_view.setText(item.getName());
    holder.sets_edit_text.setHint("" + item.getSets());
    holder.reps_edit_text.setHint("" + item.getReps());

    holder.header.setTag(holder.input);
    holder.header.setTag(R.id.tag_id, position);
    holder.header.setTag(R.id.view_id, holder.reps_edit_text);

    holder.sets_edit_text.setTag(item);
    holder.reps_edit_text.setTag(item);

    holder.sets_edit_text.addTextWatcher();
    holder.reps_edit_text.addTextWatcher();

    holder.header.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            final EditText editText = (EditText) v.getTag(R.id.view_id);

            final int a = (int) v.getTag(R.id.tag_id);
            visibleindex = a;

            View input = (View) v.getTag();
            if (input.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
            {
                input.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                visibleindex = -1;
            }
            else
            {
                //input.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });

    holder.sets_edit_text.setiOnTextChanged(new CustomEditText.IOnTextChanged()
    {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(View v, String newText)
        {
            CreateWKOItem it = (CreateWKOItem) v.getTag();
            int value = 0;
            try
            {
                String str = newText.toString();
                Log.i("su", "Sets text change to: " + str);
                if (str.length() > 0)
                    value = Integer.parseInt(str);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (it != null)
            {
                it.setSets(value);
                Log.i("su", "Current item set sets to: " + value);
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    holder.reps_edit_text.setiOnTextChanged(new CustomEditText.IOnTextChanged()
    {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(View v, String newText)
        {
            CreateWKOItem it = (CreateWKOItem) v.getTag();
            int value = 0;
            try
            {
                String str = newText.toString();
                Log.i("su", "Reps text change to: " + str);
                if (str.length() > 0)
                    value = Integer.parseInt(str);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (it != null)
            {
                it.setReps(value);
                Log.i("su", "Current item set reps to: " + value);
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    return convertView;

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I had to do is to comment out the notifyDataSetChanged(); but only on the set reps.

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution: keep your TextBox listener, and leave the brackets empty. Maybe it's Android? You could be looking at a bug.

Comment: What do you mean by keep your text box listener? Thanks

Comment: The `addTextWatcher()`. Just make the method for it blank between the brackets.